# React memo - custom equality function logic

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `ChatMessage` component like so:

```
const ChatMessage = memo(({messageObj, replyTo, newChatData, storedUsers, handleDeleteMessage, chatId, 
}, arePropsEqual)
```

`messageObj` is a simple javascript object like so: `{id: 3, text: "test"}`.

The `arePropsEqual` equality function works as expected and doesn't re-render `ChatMessage` unless the Message Object values have actually changed.

The equality function:

```
function arePropsEqual(oldProps, newProps) {
    // Logs true as expected
    console.log(JSON.stringify(oldProps.messageObj) === JSON.stringify(newProps.messageObj));
    return JSON.stringify(oldProps.messageObj) === JSON.stringify(newProps.messageObj)
}
```

Previously I used this equality function, and it did not prevent re-renders as expected:

```
function arePropsEqual(oldProps, newProps) {
    return oldProps.messageObj === newProps.messageObj
}
```

This equality function only works after adding `JSON.stringify` around the `messageObj`. Why is JSON.stringify needed? Why does this fix the issue of comparing plain javascript objects? Thanks.

Comment: They must be different references. Just because object A has the same data as object B doesn't make `===` return true. `===` (strict equality) checks if the reference of the objects is the same. By converting the data to strings (JSON.stringify), `===` no longer does a reference comparison but a value comparison instead.

Comment: @JacobSmit  Ok, so JSON.stringify converts it from an object to a  **string** data type, meaning `===` now does a value check instead of a reference check, which it was doing prior due to the data type being an object. Is this correct? Thanks.

Comment: Yep, that appears to be what is happening from the snippet you provided.